# Getting HTML object and passing it as a string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the values of id and amount from html element with jQuery, but I am trying to figure out how to get the value and pass it a string.

Here is my HTML input elements `totalAmountIn` changes value as a float number:

```html
<input type="text" value="0.00" id="totalAmountIn" readonly="readonly"></input>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <h1>Message</h1>
  <input type="text" value="" id="messageDisplay" readonly="readonly"></input>

  <h3>Item:</h3>
  <input type="text" value="" id="itemId"></input>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" id="makePurchase" class="btn btn-default">
            Make Purchase
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to use the object such as `$("#itemId")` and pass it a string using `toString()`, but I am not getting the actual input.

```
$("#makePurchase").on("click", function () {
        var id = $("#itemId").toString();
        var amount = $("#totalAmountIn").toString();
        var message = $("#messageDisplay");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/money/' + amount + '/item/' + id,
            success: function(itemInput) {
                message.val(itemInput.message);
            },
            error: function(ex) {

                message.val("error");
            }

        })

    })
```

I noticed that the each variable is being passed as `[object%20Object]`, perhaps I am not getting the value correctly, how should I be doing this?

[image]

Comment: `$("#itemId").val()` and `$("#totalAmountIn").val()`;

Comment: I was only thinking `toString()` this whole time, but what about on error or success function, I am trying to output value as shown in console, but only shows when have string type as "error". but I tried `ex.message.val()` for the error function, but not showing.

Comment: the `error` function happens when the server responds an http error. In your code you set the value of input `messageDisplay` as a static string `"error"` so when the `error` function executes it displays `error` not the exact error message

Comment: hmmm... so how could this message, "Something wasnt selected properly"  be displayed in `#messageDisplay` as shown in the console? in success? and does `itemInput.message` need to be changed to `itemInput.message.val()` as well?

Comment: Have you change the the `.toString` to `.val()`? if yes, does this message object still displays? if yes, try to check the ajax page on what output you are hoping to receive. You dont need to change it to `itemInput.message.val()` the `itemInput` variable holds the response or data outputed by your ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

The `.val()` function is what you need to use, so
`var id = $("#itemID").val();` should get you the value of the input field.

Source:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box-using-jquery.php

Answer (score 0):

> try using this and let me know if there is an error

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#makePurchase").on("click", function () {
                var id = $("#itemId").val();
                var amount = $("#totalAmountIn").val();
                var message = $("#messageDisplay");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
                     data: "amount="+ amount +"&item="+ id +"",
                    success: function(itemInput) {
                        message.val(itemInput.message);
                    },
                    error: function(ex) {

                        message.val("error");
                    }

                })

            })
        });
```